# Making a sticky div using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am currently working on a shopify store and trying to make a sticky div using jquery but unable to do that. Here is my code please have a look if Iam doing right??

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/jquery.sticky.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fixed").sticky({topSpacing:50});
  });
</script>
```

```html
<div class="main" style="width:100%;, position:absolute;">
  <div class="fixed" id="fixed" style="height: 80px; ">
    <button class="cart-btn">
IN DEN WARENKORB LEGEN</button>
</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You might now need jQuery or JavaScript: try using `position: sticky` instead of absolute. It's supported by all major browsers (except IE11, of course) https://caniuse.com/#search=position%20sticky

Comment: I have already tried that but not working

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in this line:

```
<div class="main" style="width:100%;, position:absolute;">
                                   ^^^
```

Remove the comma and it works:

```js
$("#fixed").sticky({topSpacing: 50});
```

```css
.main {
  background: #bada55;
  color: white;
  font-family: Droid Sans;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/garand/sticky@master/jquery.sticky.js"></script>



<div class="main" style="width:100%; position:absolute;">
    <div class="fixed" id="fixed" style="height: 80px; ">
        <button class="cart-btn">
            IN DEN WARENKORB LEGEN</button>
    </div>
</div>
```